# how to divide a long paragraph from API into 3 section using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular7

currently, I am trying to get a long paragraph or news into 3 sections from API so it can take a layout like in example picture. but the problem I can't divide the paragraph to make it like a layout unless I got 3 attributes for every section and just read it in angular.

I already read this [Divide HTML into pages, split long paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732742/divide-html-into-pages-split-long-paragraphs)

but it still not solve my problem, can someone help me to solve this problem only using 1 attribute?

this is my example data for news:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum natus aspernatur nihil doloribus excepturi vel sed dolores dolorum! Facere harum quia voluptates impedit praesentium. Sapiente alias consequatur sit beatae voluptatibus.
```

this is my html code :

```
    <!-- start section -->
<section class="wow fadeIn">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 d-flex flex-wrap mx-auto last-paragraph-no-margin text-center text-md-left">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 pl-0 text-center text-large md-no-padding-lr md-margin-30px-bottom">
                  <!-- start blockquote -->
                  <p class="text-extra-dark-gray margin-50px-bottom md-margin-20px-bottom alt-font">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left text-light-gray icon-medium margin-15px-bottom"></i>
                    Apa yang mendefinisikan siapa kita, tidak ada artinya dibandingkan apa yang menyatukan kita.
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-right text-right text-light-gray icon-medium margin-15px-bottom"></i>
                  </p>
                  <!-- end blockquote -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 pr-0 text-large md-no-padding-lr text-center text-md-left">
                  <p class="text-large line-height-30 text-medium-gray text-center text-md-justify sm-line-height-26">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga autem eius, hic tempore neque vel beatae facilis quaerat excepturi, minima odio dolore! Atque non quo illo, odio est vel consequuntur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quis ex aspernatur ab sunt repellat in ratione. Suscipit fugiat, sed laborum debitis, soluta dolores ipsum hic quae, corporis dignissimos unde! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus impedit repudiandae illum, incidunt tenetur sapiente ad itaque odio, ipsa cupiditate saepe omnis voluptatibus! Ipsum beatae, nihil voluptatem earum illum non. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium sunt aliquam corrupti sed voluptates, suscipit quibusdam rerum inventore molestiae, ullam fugiat ducimus, debitis mollitia consequatur. Maiores, cupiditate! Nesciunt, odio modi.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end section -->

<!-- start parallax section -->
<section class="wow fadeIn parallax p-0 height-400px md-height-200px sm-height-100px background-position-x-50 cover-background" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url('../../../assets/img/galeri/mpkmb-6.webp');">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end parallax section -->

<!-- start section -->
<section class="wow fadeIn">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 d-flex flex-wrap mx-auto last-paragraph-no-margin text-center text-md-left">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 pl-0 text-large md-no-padding-lr md-margin-30px-bottom">
                    <p class="text-large line-height-30 text-medium-gray text-center text-md-justify sm-line-height-26">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, ab minima! Aliquid unde architecto, omnis, quisquam, rem exercitationem fuga reiciendis quam voluptatibus aliquam minima aperiam dolore voluptatem sunt alias quis.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 pr-0 text-large md-no-padding-lr text-center text-md-left">
                    <p class="text-large line-height-30 text-medium-gray text-center text-md-justify sm-line-height-26">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum placeat officiis laborum. Amet harum placeat, eos, mollitia laudantium odio, quam rerum ut esse provident explicabo asperiores in possimus molestiae officia.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end section -->
```

so to sum it:

- how can I make a sentence which can continue to the next section like the layout or example image do?
- As for my code, it already done slicing the layout image but still not divide or make the news continue to the next section since in my code I divide it into 3 section

[image: example picture]

Comment: So what exactly are you asking ? Do you want to know how to split a string in three ?

Comment: Should these sections be divided as whole sentences or a sentence can continue to next section

Comment: i feel that you've failed to analyze the sites layout, this isn't achieved via positioning and splitting (you would need identifiers such as position and start and end ) but rather a wysiwyg editor like ckEditor or ngx-trumbowyg

Comment: yes, it is like splitting a string but dynamically divide it by 3 section, and fit to the layout like the image, in my code i already done slicing the layout and already got the layout like the image but the problem is I can't split the news like the layout if I got only 1 attribute from API for the whole 3 section, as for not using ckEditor or ngx-trumbowyg in the end I must use 3 text editor for 3 section so it still not solve my problem

Comment: it "a sentence can continue to the next section" like the layout

Comment: @RakisFriski uhhh no what i meant was that the whole layout you see is done via ckEditor including the image in the middle

Comment: @ImmortalDude after i check it again in ckEditor it seems the layout use text editor to make it like you said, but still is there anyway to achieve this without using text editor? it make me curious at this point

Comment: @RakisFriski reading your question carefully you want the image to appear somewhere mid in the content?

Comment: @ImmortalDude not the image but the text itself to divide into 3 section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193947/discussion-between-immortal-dude-and-rakis-friski).